# Portletfaces Bridge, Null pointer exception

Tags: liferay, portlet, icefaces

I faced problem in Icefaces portlet using portletfaces bridge inside liferay. the problem is when I open the browser for the first time I got null pointer exception. for example i opened the portal through chrome browser then open firefox, my portlet I made in ICEfaces throw null pointer exception. below you will find full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.icefaces.impl.push.servlet.ProxyHttpServletRequest.getCookies(ProxyHttpServletRequest.java:307) 
at org.icepush.PushContext.getBrowserIDFromCookie(PushContext.java:89) 
at org.icepush.PushContext.createPushId(PushContext.java:46) 
at org.icefaces.impl.push.servlet.ICEpushResourceHandler$ICEpushResourceHandlerImpl.beforePhase(ICEpushResourceHandler.java:172) 
at org.icefaces.impl.push.servlet.ICEpushResourceHandler.beforePhase(ICEpushResourceHandler.java:92) 
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228) 
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99) 
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) 
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) 
at org.portletfaces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:391) 
at org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:181) 
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328) 
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233) 
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) 
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638) 
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723) 
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425) 
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1440) 
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) 
at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:3740) 
at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1180) 
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:160) 
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:94) 
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:256) 
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:181) 
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:821) 
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) 
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:370) 
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:629) 
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:232) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) 
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) 
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:153) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) 
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:508) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:485) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:309) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:121) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:134) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:261) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.jav a:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:110) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:222) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:45) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:311) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocal.ThreadLocalFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalFilter.java:35) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) 
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I post this in portletfaces JIRA and their forum, no response so far. 
hope find the solution here, but I guess this bug in portletfaces!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it through exclude the icepush jar from my portlet! but that weird if i want to use ICEpush, will cause Exception!

Already escalate that for portletface